# How to apply clang-format --output-replacements-xml as a patch file

Tags: bash, git, clang-format

I want to get patch file to apply as:

```
git apply patch.file
```

I want to check whole project with Clang-format, but not to change files and get something like patch.file (like git diff > patch.file).
As I know the only option i can get is --output-replacements-xml, but i have not found tool to apply it automatically.

I tried to make bash script that runs clang-format on each file separately. Run git diff on each file and formatted file and save it as a patch. All patches appended to each other. It works, but very slowly. when you have 500+ files in your project bash cycle takes sufficient time. (If you run clang-format to all files not using bash cycles it runs superfast, but this way you can not get patch.file)